# Is there any difference between "my level of English" and "my standard of English"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between both sentences? Are they synonyms? Is one better for formal speaking than the other?

Recently I was rejected in a job because

> The standard of your written English is not at the level where you could write a report to our standard.

I'm trying to figure out what is the meaning of standard in that sentence, and I came across that standard also means level,

Comment: You can have a standard of English at several levels.

Comment: @mplungjan what is the meaning of the **standard**? Recently I was rejected in a job because *The standard of your written English is not at the level where you could write a report to our standard*. I'm trying to figure out what is the meaning of standard in that sentence, and I came across that **standard** also means **level**, that's why I asked if they are synonyms.

Comment: A standard is a type of measurement. Your standard of written English according to the letter you received, did not meet their requirements. Perhaps you had misspelled a word or two, hadn't used more formal expressions appropriate for writing a report, made a few punctuation errors etc. In other words, your writing didn't reach the mark (the standard) that they demand candidates should meet.

Comment: It is polite expression to tell your English is not fluent enough to meet their expectations and requirements. Maybe it is the word ordering, maybe some grammar mistakes, maybe some typos.

Comment: If that is an accurate quote from the person who rejected your application, I would suggest that perhaps (s)he is not the best person to judge: that is a horribly worded and terribly clumsy sentence—and grammatically incorrect, to boot.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet copied & pasted.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It seems a little jargony, but I'm not seeing how it's ungrammatical.

Comment: yzT’s written English may not be at the right level, but since ‘standard’ and ‘level’ are being used synonymously in this case, it makes no sense to say that his standard is not at the right level. That’s basically saying, “Your level is not at the level where …”. Perhaps more of a semantic than a grammatical issue, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite true that both *level* and *standard* can be regarded as synonymous. However, there is indeed a subtle difference between them.
Suppose there is a competition where there are ten *levels* (ten rounds; you can participate in a round only if you qualify in the preceding one). Now, there can be different players in each level. However, the *standard* of the players in each *level* differ. Agree? As in, the *quality* of players in each *level* are different. In level 8, there can be player who has just luckily cleared the seventh level. Also, there can be another player who plays extraordinarily well. This means, the standard of this player is way better than the former.
So this is where the difference between *level* and *standard* lies.
However, based on context, you can use either of them for the same purpose.

As regards to you being rejected from job, I think your boss just wanted to tell you that you don't write good  English (according to him). Simple.

Comment: Nice example. Also not all football player from Premiere League are on the same skill level, but the meet the standards to be part of their team.

Comment: Nice example ^^